# Python; MongoDB; Is there a faster way to check for missing files before requesting them? Code in post body

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I'm building a tool that gets updates for missing files within a database. It takes in two dicts containing the total count of records within different collections for both our offline copy and online copy. If the online copy has more records, it'll then look for gaps in our offline records and query for them from the online copy.

```
# Discovers gaps within records, utilizing primarykey 'id' as 1-based index
def get_missing_from(mongoDB, collection: str, total=False):
    
    # Locates gaps within a sorted array of ints
    def find_missing(lst):
        return [x for x in range(lst[0], lst[-1]+1) 
                                   if x not in lst]
    
    # Queries entire collection for 'id' of each record
    missing_ids = dict()
    lst = list(int(record.get('id')) for record in mongo_db[collection].find({}, {'id':1, '_id':0}))
    if len(lst) == 0:
        lst.append(0)
    if total: # Accounts for records missing at end of collection
        lst.append(total+1)
    
    return find_missing(lst)


# Produces dict{endpoint: [{offset: _, limit: _}, {...}]} to fill missing records
def batch_params(missing_ids: list, limit: int):
    params = list()

    first = last = missing_ids[0]
    end = missing_ids[0] + limit
    
    for _id in sorted(missing_ids):
        if _id < end:
            last = _id
        else:
            params.append(dict(offset=first-1, limit=last+1-first))
            first = last = _id
            end = _id + limit # reset the limit
            
    # append the last sublist
    params.append(dict(offset=first-1, limit=last+1-first))
    
    return params


# Returns a dict{endpoint: [{offset: _, limit: _}, {...}]} for any missing records
def update_check(request_totals, mongo_totals, max_limit=100):
    outdated = dict()
    
    # For each collection, total_records_in
    for collection, total in mongo_totals.items():
        
        # If request totals larger than mmongo
        if request_totals.get(collection, total-1) > total:
            # Get missing ids (requests total appended)
            missing_ids = get_missing_from(mongo_db, collection, total=request_totals.get(collection))
            # Create batches of params to collect missing ids
            batches = batch_params(missing_ids=missing_ids, limit=100)
            outdated.update({collection : batches})
            
        # This flag is indicative of an issue where mongo's records exceed onlines  
        elif request_totals.get(collection, total-1) < total:
            raise AttributeError(f'''
            Mongo does not appear to be a subset of requests. Review: {collection} \n 
            Mongo: {total}, Requests: {request_totals.get(collection, 'Doesnt exist')}
            ''')
    
    return outdated

updates_queue = update_check(request_totals, mongo_totals)
updates_queue
```

This takes ages though, and I believe I'm getting stuck in `get_missing_from(...).find_missing(lst)`. This is basically locating gaps within a list of numbers that should be consecutive.

Heres some sample input:

```
request_totals = {'accounts': 81679,
 'accountContacts': 137040,
 'accountCustomFieldData': 0,
 'addresses': 1,
 'automations': 41,
 'fieldValues': 1638955},

mongo_totals = {'accounts': 0,
 'accountContacts': 0,
 'accountCustomFieldData': 0,
 'addresses': 0,
 'automations': 0,
 'fieldValues': 0}
```

This is a portion of what output would look like:

```
{'accounts': [{'offset': 0, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 1900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 2900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 3900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 4900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 5900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 6900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 7900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 8900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 9900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 10900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 11900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 12900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 13900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 14900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 15900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 16900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 17900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 18900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 19900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 20900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 21900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 22900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 23900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 24900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 25900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 26900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 27900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 28900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 29900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 30900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 31900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 32900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 33900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 34900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 35900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 36900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 37900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 38900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 39900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 40900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 41900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 42900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 43900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 44900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 45900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 46900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 47900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 48900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 49900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 50900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 51900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 52900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 53900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 54900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 55900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 56900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 57900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 58900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 59900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 60900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 61900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 62900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 63900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 64900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 65900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 66900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 67900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 68900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 69900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 70900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71200, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71300, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71400, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71500, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71600, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71700, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71800, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 71900, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 72000, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 72100, 'limit': 100},
  {'offset': 72200, 'limit': 100},
...
```

It's paginated, so each of those dicts of `{'offset': , 'limit': }` are requests. It wasn't slow the first time I ran it, but the first run got interrupted and now that I'm trying to pick up where I left off, it's terribly slow.

Theres also an instance of mongodb required to be running for this code to work (under variable name `mongo_db`). It's just incredibly slow though.

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea to get missing `id` values that are expected to be sequential within documents in a collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "maxId": {"$max": "$id"},
      "idSet": {"$addToSet": "$id"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "missingIds": {
        "$setDifference": [
          {"$range": [1, "$maxId"]},
          "$idSet"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "maxId": 1,
      "missingIds": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B91_3iR0LOa).